# Active Reports not showing in Visual Studio 2010 developer edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, activereports

I've Visual Studio 2010 developer edition in my PC. Also I installed AR 9. But this is not showing under add new item. So I cant add new Active Report section report into it.

How can make the Active Reports items been visible in Visual Studio add new item option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not running the Visual Studio 2010 express edition. ActiveReports cannot be used with the express edition of Visual Studio since they do not support packages. Please check the [requirements](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/Requirements.html) page for more information.

Comment: Thats true pal... I've got the same reply from AR forums.. Thanks